# ¿Como hacen para crear un componente con el nombre del app al comienzo?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Yo he visto la html de una aplicacion de Angular recientemente que tiene componentes que comienzan con el nombre de la aplicacion.

Por ejemplo, en vez de `<app-menu></app-menu>`, dice `<concurso-app-menu></concurso-app-menu>`. El nombre del app siendo `concurso`.

Como lo hacen? Donde puedo conseguir mas informacion de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para los componentes que tengas ya creados, los tendrás que cambiar manualmente en la propiedad `selector` del decorador `@Component`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'concurso-app-menu', // <-----
  ...
})
export class MenuComponent {
  ...
}
```

Y para que los futuros elementos que generes con la cli ya utilicen directamente ese prefijo automáticamente, tienes que modificar la propiedad `prefix` de tu proyecto en el archivo `angular.json`

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "proyecto_que_quieras_modificar": {
      ...,
      "prefix": "concurso-app", //<-----
      ...
     },
   ...,
}
```

un saludo